# How to update value in different table sql

Tags: sql

I have some questions, I have 2 tables, Table a and table b.

This is what Table a looks like:

| ID | INFROMATION | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Detail Inf | 0 |
| -- | ----------- | ------ |

And this is what table b looks like:

| ID | SEQ | ITEM NAME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Item A | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | Item B | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | Item C | 2 |

My question is: how to update `a.Status` and set value to 2 with condition if all values in `b.status` are 2 and `a.id = b.id`

And of course if `Table b.status` contains a value of 0 or 1 and `a.id = b.id`, then column `a.status` is set to 1.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status in the A table appears to be derived from the state of the B table, and, as such, I would actually suggest *not* doing this update.  Instead, when you want to *view* the aggregate status, use an appropriate select query:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    INFORMATION,
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.ID = a.ID AND b.STATUS <> 2)
         THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS STATUS
FROM TableA a;
```

The logic here is that if, for a given `ID` in the A table, we *can't* find any record in the B table whose status isn't 2, then we label the overall status as 2, otherwise we label as 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'll run 2 query

```
UPDATE A
SET A.STATUS = 2
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.STATUS = 2


UPDATE A
SET A.STATUS = 1
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.STATUS <> 2
```